# Is this geometric sequence convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

2, -6, 18, -54,...

Is this geometric sequence convergent or divergent? I know that convergent sequences have terms that are approaching a constant, but how do I find out if that is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: by the way check what follows [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2C+-6%2C+18%2C+-54%2C... ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT.** What number do you continue to multiply by to get from one term to the next, i.e. what number times $2$ gives you $-6$? Then what number times $-6$ gives you $18$.... If you kept multiplying by this number, could you get 'really' close to any particular number?

Comment: The constant term I would multiply by would be -3. If I continue to multiply by -3, The numbers alternate between negative integers and positive integers, but don't really go anywhere. Does this mean that the sequence is divergent?

Comment: Indeed, if you tried to get 'close' to any number, you'd 'ruin it' by multplying by $-3$ to get the next term. For geometric series, you need the term you continue to multiply by, say $r$, to have this property $-1<r\leq 1$. The $\leq 1$ because it 'fixes' the number or shrinks it down to $0$ and we avoid $-1$ because we don't want the number to go back and forth between some number $a$ and $-a$. Try if for yourself with a calculator to see the convergence/divergence!

Comment: Makes sense now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

We have this general result:

> The geometric sequence $(a^n)$ is convergent if and only if $-1<a\le1$.

Comment: Again geometric seq to rescue. :+)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence can't be bounded by any integer - It's divergent.  The fact that it alternates between negative and positive integers doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the help.